# How to generate google cloud SSL certificate in Nginx server

Tags: magento, nginx, google-cloud-platform, cloud, magento2.1

I am new in google cloud server and I don't understand how can I generate a new SSL if they create a domain in their name. When I create a new VM in Google Cloud, it comes with a Ip domain that's not in my name.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks Folks

Comment: This isn't super clear to me.  Who is "they"?  What do you mean by "comes with an IP domain that's not in my name"?  A Google Cloud VM typically comes with an external *IP address*; it's up to you to associate it with a domain by configuring DNS somewhere.

Comment: When i want to create a new certificate, the first comodo's condition is that the domain will be in name of my company. The Virtual Machine that Google Cloud server creates is in google's name. I wanna know, if possible, how can i create a VM in Google Cloud like a domain in my name. For example: www.sergioscompany.com or a IP that will be in name of sergio's company.

Comment: You have to *register* a domain name, and then configure a DNS provider.  Google Cloud [offers DNS services](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/), but you'd still need to register a domain name first.

Comment: I will explain my job case: I have a magento's multi-store. The google cloud server works as my administration. I can create many stores with different SSL, but i want a protection on google cloud too, and the protection need to converse with all stores. My case is a Multi Domain SSL like this plan(https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/multi-domain-ssl.aspx).

Comment: Ok, but I still don't really understand what you're asking.  It still sounds like your problem is that you haven't registered a domain name, and haven't configured DNS to associate that domain name with the IP address of your VM.  Once you have done that, then you can sort out your SSL certificate(s).

Comment: The comodo says that the domain of google cloud is not in my name, so its not possible yet to create a multi domain SSL certificate. Do you know is it possible or i will have to create a single certificate of each store?

Comment: Note that in magento, i can create many stores that is in a single main server. In the case, Google Cloud Server. Each Store have different domains, and yes, each domain is in my name because i register it. But the VM's IP works as my administration, and i want to set SSL certificate in the administration too.

Comment: Why do you need to give it Google's domain?

Comment: Because the google cloud IP domain works like a administration server. For Example: When i access all stores with /admin like www.sergioscompany.com/admin, then, it redirects to VM's IP domain like 35.188.12.15 and asks for login and password to enter into administration. Note that www.sergioscompany.com is a domain in my name, with SSL certificate, but the VM's IP does not have SSL because i dont have privilege to order a new SSL to comodo.